# Package Structure for Maven Module Wise plug and Play

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, architecture, maven-3

1)

In my company management is looking for a product structure where any module can be removed with out effecting project execution i.e if a client only requires only 5 modules out of 10, they want to unplug those excessive modules and give the same product with less code modifications rather than developing again.

2)

Here one simple doubt is if Module 1 having form A and Module 2 having form B, when user performs some operation on form A then some update will happen in form B and at the same time if client does not require Module 2 ,

How to overcome scenarios like this ?

I hope there are many companies which will give the same product to different clients based on there requirements , they will plug/unplug the modules with out re-development,

What is the real time product structure for the scenarios like this.

Any sort of help is appreciable for above 2 points.

Sorry if I spelled anything wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html) is a tutorial.